# How to add Crosswalk project to Android studio?

Tags: android, gradle, crosswalk-runtime

I am trying out android crosswalk project. I am having problems adding crosswalk webview to andriod studio though. I am not sure where I am going wrong nor do I understand most terminology yet.

I read https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/embedding_crosswalk.html but I refers to https://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/eclipse-adt.html which is no longer supported. This seems to be outdated but I tried anyway with Android Studio 1.2.2.

I tried making a project with https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/downloads.html Android webview (ARM)  13.42.319.11 as told in the documention. I am not sure what is meant with 'open ADT' but I assumed Android Studio instead of the plugin of eclipse. I opened from an 'existing android studio project' (the download unzipped). But didn't come across the option 'set root directory'.

I then tried to create a new android studio project and ran it. It showed the basic hello wold example on my phone. Then I followed the remaining steps by pasting in the code they provided. I ran it again and got 3 errors:

```
Error:(3, 22) error: package org.xwalk.core does not exist
Error:(9, 13) error: cannot find symbol class XWalkView
Error:(15, 23) error: cannot find symbol class XWalkView
```

[image: Android studio]

I am not sure what to do from here as this is all very new to me.

Basically I am trying to run there example but can't figure out why the import isn't working.

Comment: Dublicate question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28781803/embed-crosswalk-in-android-studio. Please follow this Guide: https://diego.org/2015/01/07/embedding-crosswalk-in-android-studio/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49478470/3966458

Answer (score 1):

I am having the same problem but I finally fixed it by placing the xwalk_core_library.jar in the libs folder, together with arm64-v8a and x86_64 subfolders and I have removed compile 'org.xwalk:xwalk_core_library:x.x.x.x' from dependecies.

Comment: Can you show how you have achieved it? I need to make support for 64-bit version to be able to upload it on PlayStore.

Comment: Can you please share the code here , i can't understand how you did this , i need to upload to play store with 64 and 32 bit

Answer (score -1):

**Updated Links 19-07-2016**

```
   maven {
    url 'https://download.01.org/crosswalk/releases/crosswalk/android/maven2'
    }
```

And In dependencies add this

```
 compile 'org.xwalk:xwalk_core_library_beta:9.38.208.8'
```