# Install crosswalk (WebView) 13 in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, crosswalk-runtime

I found a solution in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28781803/embed-crosswalk-in-android-studio). But it's old and does not work for [latest version](https://download.01.org/crosswalk/releases/crosswalk/android/stable/13.42.319.11/arm/crosswalk-webview-13.42.319.11-arm.zip).

I tried this:

```
apply plugin: 'android-sdk-manager'
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
Repositories {
    Maven {
        url 'https://download.01.org/crosswalk/releases/crosswalk/android/maven2'
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'org.xwalk:xwalk_core_library:13.42.319.11'

    //compile ('com.github.florent37:materialviewpager:1.0.1@aar'){
    //    transitive=true
    //}

    compile project(':materialviewpager')
}
```

But I got this error:

> Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':sample'.
>
> > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':sample:_debugCompile'.
> >     Could not resolve org.xwalk:xwalk_core_library:13.42.319.11.
> >          Required by:
> >              MaterialViewPager-master:sample:unspecified
> >     Could not parse POM https://download.01.org/crosswalk/releases/crosswalk/android/maven2/org/xwalk/xwalk_core_library/13.42.319.11/xwalk_core_library-13.42.319.11.pom
> >     Already seen doctype.

Comment: do you use a proxy? if yes, maybe it forbids the connection to the repo