# Is there a XWalkView webviewclient?

Tags: java, android, android-webview, crosswalk, xwalkview

I'm trying to use **XWalkView** as webview replacement in my android app. I noticed that there's no `setWebViewClient` method on **XWalkView** object. The thing is that I want to check when the page is finished (`onPageFinished`) and when the resource is loaded (`onLoadResource`). How can I do this with **XWalkView**?

I embed the XWalkView using this tutorial

[embed crosswalk in android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28781803/embed-crosswalk-in-android-studio)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Cross Walk API introduces its own names for every component. Not only the `WebView` is renamed to `XWalkView`, but also `WebViewClient` has its counterpart named `XWalkResourceClient` and `WebChromeClient` - `XWalkUIClient`. So, instead of `setWebViewClient` you should use `setResourceClient` method and pass `XWalkResourceClient` instance to it. In this object you can implement some required methods, for example `onLoadFinished`. Please, consult with [Cross Walk API documentation](https://crosswalk-project.org/apis/embeddingapidocs_v5/index.html) for further details.

Answer (score 5):

WebViewClient example:

```
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            //Do stuff
        }
    });
```

Same thing but using XWalkView version:

```
xWalkView.setResourceClient(new XWalkResourceClient(xWalkView){
        @Override
        public void onLoadFinished(XWalkView view, String url) {
            super.onLoadFinished(view, url);
            //Do Stuff
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use ResourceClient.

```
class ResourceClient extends XWalkResourceClient {
    public ResourceClient(XWalkView xwalkView) {
        super(xwalkView);
    }

    public void onLoadStarted(XWalkView view, String url) {
        mProgress = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        mProgress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        super.onLoadStarted(view, url);
        Log.d("INFO", "Load Started:" + url);
    }

    public void onLoadFinished(XWalkView view, String url) {
        super.onLoadFinished(view, url);
        Log.d("INFO", "Load Finished:" + url);
        bottomBar = (BottomBar) findViewById(R.id.bottomBar);
        mProgress = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        mProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    public void onProgressChanged(XWalkView view, int progressInPercent) {
        super.onProgressChanged(view, progressInPercent);
        Log.d("INFO", "Loading Progress:" + progressInPercent);
        mProgress = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        mProgress.setProgress(progressInPercent);
    }
```