# How to play video fullscreen in crosswalk webview?

Tags: java, android, video, crosswalk, xwalkview

I have refer to [Playing HTML5 video on fullscreen in android webview](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15768837/6521116) to play video on full screen.

But I didn't use the native webview, I used the Crosswalk webview to play the live flv video, which is not a HTML video format. I use flv.js and xwalkwebview, the live flv video plays well, but I want to play it fullscreen.

And I have refer to [Is there a XWalkView webviewclient?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34536190/6521116). WebChromeClient of webview is corresponding to XWalkUIClient of crosswalk webview. While XWalkUIClient doesn't have somemethod like `onShowCustomView()` and `onHideCustomView()`.

So how to make it.

Comment: I use flv.js and xwalkwebview, it plays well.

Comment: Comments have made question clearer.

Comment: @MorrisonChang Thank you, I've edited my question to make clear.

Comment: Have you seen this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29700222/cant-fullscreen-html5-videos-in-chromes-webview